# How to add ANY operator into an AVG in CASE SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, average, any

We have a stored procedure that averages snow conditions on local reports and then shoots out a set percentage for the county. That county is put on an interactive map and shades of colors are applied.

In counties where there are only a few reports, the average is getting set to 0 even when there is one open business. This is a problem because the color is then indicating there are no open businesses in that county.

Our solution is to set the average to 25 if there is even one report with a condition of 'Poor', 'Fair', 'Good', 'Excellent' and to 50 if this more than one report with one of those conditions.

I tried to achieve the first objective using the ANY operator, but I'm unable to make this work. I'm also not sure how to achieve the second objective.

**This is the current query:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAverageConditionByCounty]
(   
    @SiteId int = 100
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT cg.Name,
    AVG(ISNULL(CASE sn.Condition 
        WHEN 'Poor' THEN 25 
        WHEN 'Fair' THEN 50 
        WHEN 'Good' THEN 75 
        WHEN 'Excellent' THEN 100
        ELSE 0  END,-1)) as average
    FROM Counties cg    
    INNER JOIN BaseReports br ON br.CountyId = cg.Id AND br.IsActive = 1
    INNER JOIN SnowReport sn ON sn.BaseReportId = br.Id 
    WHERE br.SiteId = @SiteId
    GROUP BY cg.Id, cg.Name
    ORDER BY cg.Name
END
```

**Here are the sample results from the original query:**

| Name | average |
| --- | --- |
| County A | 100 |
| County B | 75 |
| County C | 0 |
| County D | 0 |
| County E | 25 |

**To achieve the first objective using the ANY() operator, this is what I tried to do:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAverageConditionByCounty]
(   
    @SiteId int = 100
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT cg.Name,
    AVG(ISNULL(CASE sn.Condition 
        WHEN 'Past Peak' THEN 101
        WHEN 'Poor' THEN 25 
        WHEN 'Fair' THEN 50 
        WHEN 'Good' THEN 75 
        WHEN 'Excellent' THEN 100
        WHEN sn.Condition = ANY ('Poor', 'Fair', 'Good', 'Excellent' ) THEN 25
        ELSE 0  END,-1)) as average
    FROM Counties cg    
    INNER JOIN BaseReports br ON br.CountyId = cg.Id AND br.IsActive = 1
    INNER JOIN SnowReport sn ON sn.BaseReportId = br.Id 
    WHERE br.SiteId = @SiteId
    GROUP BY cg.Id, cg.Name
    ORDER BY cg.Name
END
```

**Error when trying ANY():**

- Incorrect syntax near '='.
- Incorrect syntax near 'Poor'. Expecting '(' or 'SELECT'.
- Incorrect syntax near 'THEN'.

**This is my attempt using the IN() operator:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAverageConditionByCounty]
(   
    @SiteId int = 100
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT cg.Name,
    AVG(ISNULL(CASE sn.Condition 
        WHEN 'Past Peak' THEN 101
        WHEN 'Poor' THEN 25 
        WHEN 'Fair' THEN 50 
        WHEN 'Good' THEN 75 
        WHEN 'Excellent' THEN 100
        WHEN sn.Condition IN ('Poor', 'Fair', 'Good', 'Excellent' ) THEN 25
        ELSE 0  END,-1)) as average
    FROM Counties cg    
    INNER JOIN BaseReports br ON br.CountyId = cg.Id AND br.IsActive = 1
    INNER JOIN SnowReport sn ON sn.BaseReportId = br.Id 
    WHERE br.SiteId = @SiteId
    GROUP BY cg.Id, cg.Name
    ORDER BY cg.Name
END
```

**Here are the errors when trying IN():**

- Incorrect syntax near 'IN'.
- Incorrect syntax near 'THEN'. Expecting ',', 'AND', or 'Or'.

Comment: Consumable sample data, and expected results, will help us help you here.

Comment: A few rows of sample data and the expected result will greatly help us to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: It seems that you need `IN()` and not `ANY()`.  You also mixing two formats of `CASE` statement together.

Comment: @PM77-1 is correct; the way you've written it, replacing `ANY` with `IN` should get you what you want. Here is the documentation on [ANY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/some-any-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). `ANY` checks that, for a given _comparison_ against elements of a subquery, at least one comparison evaluates to true. In your case, you're just checking that a column value `sn.Condition` is `IN` a list of values `('Poor', 'Fair'...)`

Comment: FYI `CASE` is not a *statement*, its an *expression*.

Comment: Side note about ANY, I have never had to use it in real life. However if you _are_ curious how ANY/SOME/ALL work, check out [ALL, ANY, and SOME: The Three Stooges](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/08/all-any-and-some-three-stooges.html) by Brad Shultz

Comment: Thank you all! I appreciate the constructive criticism and feedback. I added the errors in for attempts at using ANY() and IN(). I can't produce any results because of these errors. I'm hesitant to show results of executing the original stored procedure either because of sensitive data. Let me see what I can come up with. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my question with text instead of images and added errors and sample data. Thank you again.

Comment: Your CASE expression makes no sense to me. Everything in the IN / ANY expression already precedes it in the CASE logic. In other words, that line would never, ever, get reached.  `CASE WHEN x=1 THEN 'a' WHEN x=2 THEN 'b' WHEN X IN (1,2) THEN 'this never happens, ever, ever' END`

Comment: I strongly recommend you delete this question and open a new one with a full [mre] as recommended here : [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: You can't combine the 2 different `case` expression syntaxes you are attempting to use. If you use `case condition when` then every when can only contain a constant - not an expression. Otherwise every when has to contain an expression and no constant. Check the documtation, its one or the other, not both.

Comment: BTW: The `avg()` aggregate will disregard nulls. As written you wouldn't have any null results so you don't need the `isnull()`. And if you had snuck in a -1 into the mix then that would definitely throw off the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want something more like this:

```
case count(case when sn.Condition in ('Poor', 'Fair', 'Good', 'Excellent') then 1 end)
    -- if those are all the possibilities then just use count(*) instead
    when 1 then 25
    when 2 then 50
    else avg(case sn.Condition 
                 when 'Poor' then 25 
                 when 'Fair' then 50 
                 when 'Good' then 75 
                 when 'Excellent' then 100
                 else 0 end)
end as "average"
```

It also gives you a flavor of both types of `case` expressions.

You could also guarantee that the calculation can't dip below 25 by taking advantage of nulls which will always be ignored. Since the lowest contributor to the calculation is 25, an average lower than that is then impossible, although it could still evaluate to null in the case of no inputs. (`else null` is also the default behavior when not explicitly specified):

```
coalesce(avg(case sn.Condition 
            when 'Poor' then 25 
            when 'Fair' then 50 
            when 'Good' then 75 
            when 'Excellent' then 100
            else null end), 0) as "average"
```